# Facebook graph api - returns pages in random order

Tags: php, facebook, laravel, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to retrieve pages for which a user is an admin via the graph api. I've given the manage_pages permission to my application however, making a call:

```
<user-id>/accounts
```

returns a set of pages but it doesn't return all the pages that the user can access as an admin user also the pages seem to be in some random messed up order. Its not alphabetically ordered nor is it even ordered by ID. Is there a way to get all pages as in all pages a user has access to and that too ordered alphabetically atleast.

Comment: Either specify a higher `limit`, or use pagination. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/#paging (Since the maximum limit you can choose is limited, you should perhaps rather implement pagination anyway.) After you got all pages - order them as you like on your end.

Comment: Hmmm thats the weird thing I'm not getting all the pages even if I specify a larger limit. For example I have admin access to 42 pages but if I specify a limit of 100 only 30 pages show up? Is there a certain permission or role I need to have for these pages?

Comment: You need to be a page admin.

Comment: Just checked - I added a total_count and it returns 41 as total_count in smmary but only 39 pages are returned in the response. Is there any kind of privacy setting that I need to look at here?

Comment: Dunno. Can you identify which pages are missing?

Comment: I can see the pages on facebook - however the api doesn't return them. I have admin access to them all btw. Is there something I'm missing here.

Comment: It should return all pages you have admin level access to. If it doesn’t, and you are sure that is not an issue with limits resp. pagination, then file a bug report. https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/